# MS Graph: How to get access token using certificate from Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

In Asp.Net 4.8 MVC application, I would like to get access token using certificate (self-sgined cert) from Azure AD. All the example I have seen are  using client secret. I'm new to Azure AD, so it will be great if someone can point me to a sample that uses certificate.

So far I have googled and examples that I have seen on MS site are using client secret.

Comment: Where is the certificate stored in Azure AD? In Azure Key Vault?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to get access token from Console App using client certificate and got below results:***

I created one self-signed certificate from PowerShell using below script:

```
$certname = "sricert"    
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.cer"   ## Specify your preferred location
```

**Response:**

[image]

To export the above certificate in **`.pfx`** format, I ran below commands:

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -Force -AsPlainText 
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.pfx" -Password $mypwd
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD application and added **client certificate** with **`.cer`** format like this:

[image]

I ran below **c# code** including certificate path in my console app and got access token successfully like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

// Load the certificate from a file
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:/test/sricert.pfx", "password");

// Create the confidential client application object
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("appID")
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>"))
    .Build();

// Get the access token
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

// Print the access token
Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", authResult.AccessToken);
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got **claims** like below:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear from the question but I think that the certificate is stored in Azure not on local machine. Do you know how to get the certificate stored in Azure using .NET 4.8?