# Retrieved assigned App Roles using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to retrieve, with Terraform, the assigned App roles to a given user. I can assign roles using resources `azuread_app_role_assignment`.

The final goal is assign an App roles only if it's not already assigned.

Trying to *re-assign* an App role would result in the plan failing.

**EDIT 1**

It's not possible to do so using Terraform. Thus, I have to rely on an external script for performing it. Essentially, create `null_resource` or `external` data resource, and perform the checks using Graph API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The final goal is assign an App roles only if it's not already assigned.

There is no direct way via `Terraform`, you can use a **PowerShell** script inside Terraform by employing the `null_resource`.

Here is the `PowerShell` script to check the app roles for the user and assign the role if it is not already assigned.

**script.ps1**

```
    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "226cfxxxxxxxx-4005-acfb-9bbfa7d40283" -ApplicationId "bf7exxxxxxx-10f90c4811d2" -CertificateThumbprint "B4BBECE1xxxxxEB4B867115717"
    # Define variables
    $userObjectId = "d0exxxx16-d3925da28976"
    $appName = "venkatapp"
    
    # Get the user and service principal information
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $userObjectId
    $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$appName'"
    
    # Get the app role assignments for the user
    $existingAssignments = Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userObjectId
    
    # If you want to assign all available roles
    foreach ($appRole in $servicePrincipal.AppRoles) {
        $roleId = $appRole.Id
    
        # Check if the role is already assigned
        $alreadyAssigned = $existingAssignments.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $roleId }
    
        # Assign the app role if not already assigned
        if (-not $alreadyAssigned) {
            try {
                New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $roleId
    
                Write-Output " ------------------------------------------------- "
                Write-Output "App role with ID '$roleId' assigned successfully."
            }
            catch {
                # Check if the error is related to the assignment already existing
                if ($_.Exception.Message -notlike "*Permission being assigned already exists*") {
                    throw
                }
                else {
                    Write-Output "App role with ID '$roleId' is already assigned to the user."
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Terraform file**

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    resource "null_resource" "execute_powershell" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
          powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ${path.module}/script.ps1
        EOT
      }
    }
```

Make sure to place the `PowerShell` script in the same directory.

After running the script, the app roles will be assigned to the application.

[image]

Refer the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75514466/ms-graph-how-to-get-access-token-using-certificate-from-azure/75517217#75517217) for creating self signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer. I got it solved it a few days before you posted your answer, using also `null_resource` and a Bash script.